# How can I reset the iid counter in ttk.treeview python

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

I have a python program which populates a treeview table with data based on a search string. I am then using  the .selected and iid attribute to access the original list with all data in and pull out everything relating to the selected item.

I am having an issue when attempting a second search. I first run the line of code below which vissibly clears the table however when I add the items from the new search the first index or iid is the last one from the previous search plus one.

```
searchResults.delete(*searchResults.get_children())
```

How can I reset the iid value so the first entry of the second search goes in at I001

The method I am using to populate the treeview with data is

```
for i in range(0,(len(chemList))):
            searchResults.insert("","end", text=serialNumber, values = (itemName,ownerName,location)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: please create a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

The `iid` can be passed as an `insert` argument. It should not already exist in the treeview, otherwise a new one is created.

From Python help

```
Help on method insert in module tkinter.ttk:

insert(parent, index, iid=None, **kw) method of tkinter.ttk.Treeview instance
...
```

It will just work as usual or with given `iid`, but I don't know about a reset option though. And it does not seem to start from then on, too, although it reuses available `iids`